# list comprehension in python and its alternative

Tags: python, python-3.x

The problem statement is to apply `isalpha, isdigit, isnumeric, islower` to a string. I want to use code that performs this operation. So far I came up with this

```
string='Ab65GH'
any(eval(c.i for c in string) for i in "isalpha() isdigit() islower() isnumeric()".split())
```

The output can be formatted to look like a list of booleans joined by '\n'.
Please provide solutions on how to improvise/complete the above code and your alternative approaches

Comment: do you want to test each character? or the whole string? that's not the same _at all_

Comment: Do you need both `isdigit` and `isnumeric` ?  Could you show  the expected output?

Comment: In the first line, print True if  has any alphanumeric characters. Otherwise, print False. 
In the second line, print True if  has any alphabetical characters. Otherwise, print False. 
In the third line, print True if  has any digits. Otherwise, print False. 
In the fourth line, print True if  has any lowercase characters. Otherwise, print False. 
In the fifth line, print True if  has any uppercase characters. Otherwise, print False.

Answer (score 2):

you probably want to test the *whole* string, not each character separately.

In that case, you could apply each functions and *not* using `eval` which is overkill here, and generally unsafe.

```
any(f(string) for f in [str.isalpha,str.isdigit,str.islower,str.isnumeric])
```

`str.isdigit(string)` is the functional notation for `string.isdigit()`.

For each character you would do:

```
print(any(f(c) for c in string for f in [str.isalpha,str.isdigit,str.islower,str.isnumeric]))
```

But that would always return `True` unless the string is only made of symbols.

Comment: print(any(f(c) for c in string for f in [str.isalpha,str.isdigit,str.islower,str.isnumeric])) returns True just once, but I am expecting  that once a result is printed, it should print 'True' for isalpha, isdigit, islower and isnumeric.

Answer (score 1):

I feel this should really be just:

```
s = 'Ab65GH'
return s.isalpha() or s.isdigit() or s.islower() or s.isnumeric()
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you are in need of:

```
s='Ab65GH'
for i in s:
      print i,i.isdigit(),i.isalpha(),i.islower(),i.isnumeric()
```

Comment: *The function isnumeric() doesn't seem supported* - that's because you are using the old Python 2.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using regular expressions.  Normally the `str` methods would be preferred, but we would have to perform these on each character which would *probably* negate any performance advantage.  Using an RE removes the need for multiple loops.

```
import re

string = 'Ab65GH'
#In the first line, print True if has any alphanumeric characters. Otherwise, print False. 
print(bool(re.search(r'[A-Za-z0-9]', string)))

#In the second line, print True if has any alphabetical characters. Otherwise, print False. 
print(bool(re.search(r'[A-Za-z]', string)))

#In the third line, print True if has any digits. Otherwise, print False.
print(bool(re.search(r'[0-9]', string)))

#In the fourth line, print True if has any lowercase characters.  Otherwise, print False.  
print(bool(re.search(r'[a-z]', string)))

#In the fifth line, print True if has any uppercase characters. Otherwise, print False
print(bool(re.search(r'[A-Z]', string)))
```

Gives:

```
True
True
True
True
True
```